# Redux: Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have decided to break up my redux store—to now represent logical buckets i.e. `users, ui` etc.

These are the files which each contain the initial state, action types and reducers for each category:

*ui reducer file*:

```
/*./reducers/ui/index' reducer for ui */

/* initial state */
export const uiStartState = { ui: { modalActive: false } }

/* action types */
export const actionTypes = {
    ui: { MODAL_ACTIVE: 'MODAL_ACTIVE' },
    ui: { MODAL_INACTIVE: 'MODAL_INACTIVE' },
}

/* reducer(s) */
export default function ui(state = uiStartState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.MODAL_ACTIVE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { ui: { modalActive: true } });
        case actionTypes.MODAL_INACTIVE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { ui: { modalActive: false } });

        default:
            return state
    }
};

/* actions */
export const modalStateOn = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.ui.MODAL_ACTIVE }
}
export const modalStateOff = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.ui.MODAL_INACTIVE }
}
```

*users reducer file*:

```
/*./reducers/users/index' reducer for ui */

/* initial state */
export const usersStartState = { users: { isLoggedIn: false } }

/* action types */
export const actionTypes = {
    users: { IS_LOGGED_IN: 'IS_LOGGED_IN' },
    users: { IS_LOGGED_OUT: 'IS_LOGGED_OUT' },
}

/* reducer(s) */
export default function users(state = usersStartState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                users: { isLoggedIn: true }
            });
        case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                users: { isLoggedIn: false }
            });
        default:
            return state
    }
};

/* actions */
export const logInUser = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN }
}
export const logOutUser = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT }
}
```

And this is my store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'

/* imported reducers */
import ui from './reducers/ui/index'
import users from './reducers/users/index'

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

var rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ui,
    users
})

export default () => {
    let store;
    const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';
    if (isClient) {
        const { persistReducer } = require('redux-persist');
        const storage = require('redux-persist/lib/storage').default;
        const persistConfig = {
            key: 'primary',
            storage,
            whitelist: ['isLoggedIn', 'modalActive'], // place to select which state you want to persist

        }
        store = createStore(
            persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer), {
                ui: { modalActive: false },
                users: { isLoggedIn: false }
            },
            composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(
                thunkMiddleware,
                createLogger({ collapsed: false })
            ))
        );
        store.__PERSISTOR = persistStore(store);
    } else {
        store = createStore(
            rootReducer, {
                ui: { modalActive: false },
                users: { isLoggedIn: false }
            },
            composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(
                thunkMiddleware,
                createLogger({ collapsed: false })
            ))
        );
    }
    return store;
};
```

So taking my `actions` from `users`:

```
export const logInUser = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN }
}
export const logOutUser = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT }
}
```

Not sure why the error is saying I don't have a `key` with the name `type`, I assume it's a matter of restructuring.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I am wondering if the problem is I am merging the new state incorrectly?

From my reducer:

```
case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
         users: { isLoggedIn: true }
         });
```

My state feedback from redux tools:

You can see the `next state` the `users` object gets another `users` object nested in the orignal with the correct payload!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user action types must be in this format:

```js
export const actionTypes = {
  users: { IS_LOGGED_IN: "IS_LOGGED_IN", IS_LOGGED_OUT: "IS_LOGGED_OUT" }
};
```

With your code, `actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN`  will be `undefined`, because you have the same key in the same object, and it will be replaced. This is the reason why redux complains.

Also ui action types must be:

```js
export const actionTypes = {
  ui: { MODAL_ACTIVE: "MODAL_ACTIVE", MODAL_INACTIVE: "MODAL_INACTIVE" }
};
```

May be you can keep all your action types in a single object like this:

```js
export const actionTypes = {
  users: { IS_LOGGED_IN: "IS_LOGGED_IN", IS_LOGGED_OUT: "IS_LOGGED_OUT" },
  ui: { MODAL_ACTIVE: "MODAL_ACTIVE", MODAL_INACTIVE: "MODAL_INACTIVE" }
};
```

Update: about your question merging state:

Can you try like this?

```
export default function users(state = usersStartState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: {
          ...state.users,
          isLoggedIn: true
        }
      };
    case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: {
          ...state.users,
          isLoggedIn: false
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Like I noted above, maybe I'm merging the new state incorrectly?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz  you shouldn't update my answer with  your question:)  I need to check your new question, but I think we resolved the issue in your original question.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz I updated the question, with a try. Can you check? But anyway even if the state problem exists, I think this answer may be accepted as answer because it resolves your question. Mixing questions is not good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204569/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-antonio-pavicevac-ortiz).